# Make a get/post request within controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, controller

I have following code as action in controller:

```
class BuildPagesController < ApplicationController
 def add
  email= "abc@yahoo.com"
  name= "abc"
  # I want to make a get request/call 
  # such as localhost:3000/save?email=abc@yahoo.com&name=abc 

 #I tried the following but my console simply freezes
    post_url = "http://localhost:3000/save?email=abc@yahoo.com&name=abc"
    address = URI(URI.encode("#{post_url}"))
    http = Net::HTTP.new address.host, address.port
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new address.request_uri
    http.start


 end
end
```

Another controller is as follows:

```
class SavePagesController < ApplicationController
 def save
  Page.create(email: params[:email], name: params[:name])      
 end
end
```

routes.rb  is as follows:

```
  match 'add', to: 'build_pages#add', via: [:get,:post]
  match "save" => "save_pages#save", via: [:get,:post]
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Just create and save it. If you have business logic around that save then create a class/context/whatever and do the save through that, unless it's small enough it can go in the model itself.

Comment: I am just playing aroung with various methods to save data. I found that it would be interesting to fnd out if we can save it thorugh an existing route to that controller

Comment: Sure, you could make a request to your own app. No good reason to in this case, IMO.

Comment: Yes, But I tried the following way to add data:
        post_url = "http://localhost:3000/save?email=abc@yahoo.com&name=abc"
        address = URI(URI.encode("#{post_url}"))
        http = Net::HTTP.new address.host, address.port
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new address.request_uri
        http.start

Comment: That's the long way around; why not use a simpler gem to encapsulate all the work? Again, seems like a bad idea. If nothing else I'd move all that work into something else so the mainline controller code isn't polluted with unrelated stuff.

Comment: I imagine it wouldn't work (well) in a single-threaded environment :)